# Screen Display in Ubuntu (with DisplayLink adapter)

Tags: graphics, displaylink

Since a while ago I wanted to use my laptop with 2 more screens (3 screens in total). I recently bought an USB to VGA adapter in order to set up the third one but apparently it only works on Windows.

Anyone knows how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

These links might help you out.

Have a look here:
http://www.displaylink.com/downloads

Some info on open source drivers (Libdlo)
https://libdlo.freedesktop.org/wiki/

Good luck!

Comment: sound as great as expensive hehe. i though just installing something i could do it although probably this device is the best solution.

thanks

Comment: Hi E.F
have you ever used a universal dock station? i wonder if you know one which works fine with Ubuntu. Just tried with iTec and it was impossible.

Comment: I don't have any experience with universal dock stations. But my tip would be to search for products that have Ubuntu support. I think you can find some if you would do a search. Also, search for the experience people have had with that product using Ubuntu to be sure it is working well. Good luck!